# Explorer from within Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, tree

Basically, i want to create an extremely basic version of OneNote but with a retro style.
I lack the programming skills to create this (ive been trying), but i was wondering if maybe it could be done in Excel?

Is there a way to create a sort of directory tree of excel sheets within one excel, then be able to open one of those sheets in the same window? See attached mock-up example.

Thank you so much!
Please do not hesitate to contact me with any questions or concerns.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfnnd.png)

Comment: Its possible through VBA, but that is so advanced, I doubt you can get that to work. I'm very skilled and such project would take me a week at least.

Comment: This is not a simple requirement, it is difficult to find some reference for you, it requires very skilled coding ability